# Suppress inspection for entire file in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, inspection

We can suppress inspections using special comments like this one: `// noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall`, but it only works for a next line of code.

I have a big test suite where I call functions and ignore the returned promises. I don't want to add `// noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall` comment for each call.

Is there a way to disabled some specific inspection for an entire file?

Answer (score 3):

Yup. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a warning, right arrow key > **Suppress for file**:

[image]

Comment: Some inspections can be suppressed for file, others - not; *Result of method call returning promise is ignored* inspection can only be suppressed for current statement, it can't be disabled on file level.

Comment: What I'd like to know is how to revert this. If I decide that I want to show the warnings again in that particular file, how do I turn them on again?

Comment: Oh, now I see it adds an annotated comment on the first code line.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to disable JS inspection for an entire life.

But there is a feature request for this case, you can vote for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24722